# I can display data through a method, but not through a computed property. Why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array prop "Hotels", which consists of a nested array of hotels, which consists of various values, such as number of rooms.
To show the values, I have an array which stores an icon, a name and a function. The function is called in a method and then I loop through the array with v-for.

The problem is that I would like for the array to be reactive, so I tried moving the method into a computed property, but when doing so my data will no longer display.
What am I missing?

This is the template content:

```
      <ul class="mb-2">
        <li class="list-group-item mb-1">
        </li>
        <template v-for="(item, index) in facilities">
          <li :key="index" v-if="item.function != null">
            <i :class="item.iconClass"></i>
            {{ item.name }}
            <strong class="ml-2"> {{ item.function }} </strong>
          </li>
        </template>
      </ul>
```

The script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      hotels: Array,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        facilities: [
          {
            iconClass: "fas fa-door-open fa-fw fa-lg icon-class ml-2 mr-2",
            name: 'Number of rooms:',
            function: this.numberOfRooms,
          }
        ],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      numberOfRooms(){
        if(this.hotels[0].hotel.numberRooms > 0) {
          return this.hotels[0].hotel.numberRooms
        }
      },
    }
  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to define `facilities` as a computed property :

```js
  export default {
    props: {
      hotels: Array,
    },
    computed: {
      numberOfRooms(){
        if(this.hotels[0].hotel.numberRooms > 0) {
          return this.hotels[0].hotel.numberRooms
        }
      },
      facilities(){
        return [
          {
            iconClass: "fas fa-door-open fa-fw fa-lg icon-class ml-2 mr-2",
            name: 'Number of rooms:',
            function: this.numberOfRooms,
          }
        ],
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @brahim, good solution, and you still didn't answer the why :)

Comment: if a property depends on other one it should be computed